'torch' has no attribute 'float8_e4m3fn'
I am using Python 3.10.12 in Juppiter Lab. While running the script (from here) I keep receiving the following error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jupyter/work/resources/evalatin2024-latinpipe/latinpipe_evalatin24.py", line 25, in <module>
    import keras
  File "/home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from keras.api import DTypePolicy
  File "/home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/api/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from keras.api import activations
  File "/home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/api/activations/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from keras.src.activations import deserialize
  File "/home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.src import activations
  File "/home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/activations/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from keras.src.activations.activations import elu
  File "/home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/activations/activations.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.src import backend
  File "/home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from keras.src.backend.torch import *  # noqa: F403
  File "/home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/torch/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from keras.src.backend.torch import core
  File "/home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/torch/core.py", line 47, in <module>
    "float8_e4m3fn": torch.float8_e4m3fn,
AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'float8_e4m3fn'

I understand the problem concerns torch, and I have tried upgraging and downgrading it, but for no good. !nvidia-smi tells that my virtual machine has CUDA-12.2.
Here are some of the installed packages:
keras                            3.5.0
nvidia-cublas-cu12               12.1.3.1
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12           12.1.105
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12           12.1.105
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12         12.1.105
nvidia-cudnn-cu12                9.1.0.70
nvidia-cufft-cu12                11.0.2.54
nvidia-tensorrt                  99.0.0
pip                              23.0.1
tensorflow                       2.17.0
tensorflow-datasets              4.9.2
tensorflow-estimator             2.12.0
tensorflow-gcs-config            2.12.0
tensorflow-hub                   0.14.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem     0.32.0
tensorflow-metadata              1.13.1
tensorflow-probability           0.20.1
tensorrt                         10.3.0
tensorrt-cu12                    10.3.0
tensorrt-cu12-bindings           10.3.0
tensorrt-cu12-libs               10.3.0
torch                            2.0.1+cu118
torchaudio                       2.0.2+cu118
torchdata                        0.6.1
torchsummary                     1.5.1
torchtext                        0.15.2
torchvision                      0.15.2+cu118
transformers                     4.43.2

print(torch.version.cuda) returns 11.8 (which is the version required by the program I use). I am not even sure that this is relevant for the error I get, but some discussions suggest that it might be caused by a conflict. I did not manage to downgrade the system's CUDA.

You have a too old version of PyTorch installed

That is an 8-bit floating point format.  It requires a Ada Lovelace or Hopper GPU, and requires a newer version of CUDA than 11.8.  The CUDA 12.x stuff in your machine may be OK, but the cuda 11.8 that torch was built against is a problem, perhaps.

I have upgraded torch to 2.4.0,  torchvision to 0.19.0, and torchaudio 2.4.0. After this, I cannot import torch at all, the error is undefined symbol: ncclCommRegister.

Upgrade torch to 2.4.1 can solve it.
pip install --upgrade torch torchvision
